# ReactJS Find Array Prevent Return Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to get the brandName inside the brandData
But when the productBrandID isn't available in the brandData, it returned undefined
I don't want this happened, i want it return a value like --- Select Brand --- or what

```
              <select className="form-control" id="productBrand" name="productBrand" value={productForm.productBrand} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}>
                <option value={productForm.productBrandID}>
                  {productForm.productBrandID ? brandData.find(brand => brand.id === productForm.productBrandID).brandName : '--- Select Brand ---'}
                </option>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, handle the case where `.find()` doesn't find a match.  You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for that:

```
brandData.find(brand => brand.id === productForm.productBrandID)?.brandName
```

Second, now that this can safely return no value (instead of throwing an error) then you can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to supply a default value:

```
brandData.find(brand => brand.id === productForm.productBrandID)?.brandName ?? '--- Select Brand ---'
```

Once you have that, determine if the logic you *already have* is valid at all.  Will `productForm.productBrandID` ever be `null` or `undefined`?  And if it is, will any `brandData` record have a `null` or `undefined` value for its `id`?  I wouldn't expect so, so this new logic can probably entirely replace the logic you have:

```
<option value={productForm.productBrandID}>
  {brandData.find(brand => brand.id === productForm.productBrandID)?.brandName ?? '--- Select Brand ---'}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not 100% sure about this, but worthy try.

```
 {productForm.productBrandID ? brandData.find(brand => brand.id === productForm.productBrandID).brandName || '--- Select Brand ---' : '--- Select Brand ---'}
```